# Multiple tabItems in one shiny module

Tags: r, shiny, module, shinydashboard

Hello im relatively new to R Programming and Shiny.
I´m currently developing an shiny dashboard application.
I´m stuck a the moment with the problem of how to have multiple tabItems in one module.
In the real app I need to pass a lot more information's between the modules and the submenu's aren't alike. So is there a way to make this work?
Thanks so much for your help!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydasboardPlus)

#submodules
submodule_ui <- function(id,tabName){
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tabItem(
    tabName = tabName,
    boxPlus(
      title = "some title",
      textOutput(ns("some_output"))
    )
  )
  
}

submodule_server <- function(id,see){
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session){
      output$some_output <- renderText({
        see
      })
    }
  )
}


#module
module_ui <- function(id,tabName1,tabName2){
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  submodule_ui(ns("sub1"),
               tabName = tabName1)
  submodule_ui(ns("sub2"),
               tabName = tabName2)
  
}

module_server <- function(id){
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session){
      submodule_server("sub1","hello")
      submodule_server("sub2","world !")
    }
  )
}


#app

ui <- dashboardPagePlus(
  header = dashboardHeaderPlus(
    title = "dummy app"
  ),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem(
        text = "home",
        tabName = "home"
      ),
      menuItem(
        text = "submodule1",
        tabName = "subtab1"
      ),
      menuItem(
        text = "submodule2",
        tabName = "subtab2"
      ),
      menuItem(
        text = "some other tabItems",
        tabName = "some_other_tabItems"
      )
    )
  ),
  body = dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "home",
        box(
          title = "home of the app",
          width = "auto"
        )
      ),
      module_ui(
        id = "module",
        tabName1 = "subtab1",
        tabName2 = "subtab2"
      ),
      tabItem(
        tabName = "some_other_tabItems",
        box(
          title = "some other content"
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  module_server("module")
}

shinyApp(ui,server)

´´´
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears there was some issues with getting the tab item wrapper around the submodules - it was only producing the second submodule. Modules act like functions as they tend to produce the final call. You can wrap things in a `list` or `taglist` to return more items. In the meantime...

By moving the `tabItems` wrapper into the module, it was able to create the list properly and produce both tabs.

Note: I converted the functions to `shinydashboard` as I could figure out where the `xxxPlus` functions came from.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
#submodules
submodule_ui <- function(id,tabName){
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tabItem(
    tabName = tabName,
    box(
      title = "some title",
      textOutput(ns("some_output"))
    )
  )
  
}

submodule_server <- function(id,see){
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session){
      output$some_output <- renderText({
        see
      })
    }
  )
}


#module
module_ui <- function(id,tabName1,tabName2){
  ns <- NS(id)
  ### tabsItems now produced in module, submodules separated by comma
  tabItems(
    submodule_ui(ns("sub1"),
                 tabName = tabName1),
    submodule_ui(ns("sub2"),
                 tabName = tabName2)
  )
  
  
}

module_server <- function(id){
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session){
      submodule_server("sub1","hello")
      submodule_server("sub2","world !")
    }
  )
}


#app

ui <- dashboardPage(
  header = dashboardHeader(
    title = "dummy app"
  ),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem(
        text = "submodule1",
        tabName = "subtab1"
      ),
      menuItem(
        text = "submodule2",
        tabName = "subtab2"
      )
    )
  ),
  body = dashboardBody(
  
      module_ui(
        id = "module",
        tabName1 = "subtab1",
        tabName2 = "subtab2"
      
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  module_server("module")
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Sadly I forgot to include in the dummy app, that I have several other tabItems as well. Because of that I cant use your solution since it causes this error : error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Expected tag to have class 'tab-pane' . I´m still very grateful for your help! I´ve edited my question accordingly. I´m using shinydashboardPlus as well, thats where the xxxPlus functions are coming from.

Comment: Unfortunately, the fundamental problem is still the same: returning multiple UI elements from a module function requires a list or tagList which is going to cause you some problems with this particular setup. I'd advise you use a consistent UI pattern for tabs and utilize `conditionalPanel` for a more adaptive UI.