# How to update progress bar across over several modules and app in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, module, shinydashboard

Hi I´m very new to R programming.
Currently I´m working on a dashboard to create some data and display it.
This project got quite big quite quickly so I'm trying to modularize the dashboard.
That caused me the some problems. One being this [Multiple tabItems in one shiny module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64122281/multiple-tabitems-in-one-shiny-module).
Another being that I want / need to provide a progress bar for the user since the data processing takes up quite some time.
This processing of data is now divided in multiple modules like in the example below.
But the bar won't update itselfe further than the first module.
My guess is that the id's aren't matching and therefor the following updates aren't found.
I ain´t have any idea to "isolate" the id of `updateProgressBar()` and pass it across the modules.
Thanks so much for your help!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyWidgets)

#module_1
module_1_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(
    boxPlus(
      title = "some title",
      textOutput(ns("some_output"))
    )
  )
  
}

module_1_server <- function(id,see){
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session){
      ns <- session$ns
      
      observe({
        progressSweetAlert(
          id = ns("progress"),
          session = session,
          value = 1,
          total = 4,
        )
        Sys.sleep(1) #dummy for some functions that take some time to process
        
        updateProgressBar(
          id = ns("progress"),
          session = session,
          value = 2,
          total = 4
        )
        
      })
      
      output$some_output <- renderText({
        see
      })
    }
  )
}


#module_1
module_2_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(
    boxPlus(
      title = "some title",
      textOutput(ns("some_output"))
    )
  )
  
}

module_2_server <- function(id,see){
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session){
      ns <- session$ns
      
      observe({
        updateProgressBar(
          session = session,
          id = ns("progress"),
          value = 3,
          total = 4
        )
        
        Sys.sleep(4) #dummy for some functions that take some time to process
        
        updateProgressBar(
          session = session,
          id = ns("progress"),
          value = 4,
          total = 4
        )
        
        Sys.sleep(2)
        
        closeSweetAlert(session = session) 
        
      })
      
      output$some_output <- renderText({
        see
      })
      
      
    }
  )
}


#app

ui <- dashboardPagePlus(
  header = dashboardHeaderPlus(
    title = "dummy app"
  ),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem(
        text = "home",
        tabName = "home"
      ),
      menuItem(
        text = "module_1",
        tabName = "tab_1"
      ),
      menuItem(
        text = "module_2",
        tabName = "tab_2"
      ),
      menuItem(
        text = "some other tabItems",
        tabName = "some_other_tabItems"
      )
    )
  ),
  body = dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "home",
        box(
          title = "home of the app",
          width = "auto"
        )
      ),
      tabItem(
        tabName = "tab_1",
        module_1_ui(
          id = "module_1"
        )
      ),
      tabItem(
        tabName = "tab_2",
        module_2_ui(
          id = "module_2"
        )
      ),
      tabItem(
        tabName = "some_other_tabItems",
        box(
          title = "some other content"
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  module_1_server(
    id = "module_1",
    see = "something happens here"
  )
  module_2_server(
    id = "module_2",
    see = "something happens here as well"
  )
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Not sure it's possible because `ns("progress")` in module 1 creates a different id than in module 2. You could replace `ns("progress")` in module 2 by `"module_1-progress"` (which is the id given by `ns("progress")` in module 1), but then the problem would be the `session` argument in `updateProgressBar()`. I think you shouldn't divide your progress bar between two modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would push the progress update to the main app and let the modules simply notify the main app that it should update the progress bar. As it was not clear from your code how (in which sequence) the modules do their job and how the first module is strated, I made some assumptions:

1. The code ist started with a press on the *Start* button.
2. The first module does only one update. Once it is finished it notifies the second module to start.
3. The second module starts once the first module is finished and does 3 steps.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

m1_ui <- function(id) {
   ns <- NS(id)
   boxPlus(
      title = "Module 1",
      textOutput(ns("text_output"))
   )
}

m1_server <- function(id, content, start) {
   moduleServer(id,
                function(input, output, session) {
                   trigger_update <- reactiveVal(0)
                   finished       <- reactiveVal(FALSE)
                   
                   observeEvent(start(), {
                      Sys.sleep(1)
                      trigger_update(trigger_update() + 1)
                      finished(rnorm(1))
                   }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
                   
                   output$text_output <- renderText(content)
                   
                   list(trigger_update = trigger_update,
                        finished       = finished)
                })
   
}

m2_ui <- function(id) {
   ns <- NS(id)
   boxPlus(
      title = "Module 2",
      textOutput(ns("text_output"))
   )
}

m2_server <- function(id, content, start) {
   moduleServer(id,
                function(input, output, session) {
                   trigger_update    <- reactiveVal(0)
                   trigger_next_step <- reactiveVal(0)
                   finished          <- reactiveVal(FALSE)
                   
                   observeEvent(start(), {
                      Sys.sleep(1)
                      trigger_update(trigger_update() + 1)
                      trigger_next_step(1)
                   }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
                   
                   observeEvent(trigger_next_step(), {
                      Sys.sleep(1)
                      trigger_update(trigger_update() + 1)
                      if (trigger_next_step() <= 2) {
                         trigger_next_step(trigger_next_step() + 1)
                      } else {
                         finished(TRUE)
                      }
                   }, ignoreInit = TRUE
                   )
                   
                   output$text_output <- renderText(content)
                   
                   list(trigger_update = trigger_update,
                        finished       = finished)
                })
}

ui <- dashboardPagePlus(
   dashboardHeaderPlus(
      title = "dummy app"
   ),
   dashboardSidebar(),
   dashboardBody(fluidRow(actionButton("start", "Start")), 
                 fluidRow(m1_ui("m1"), m2_ui("m2")))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   m1_handler <- m1_server("m1", "text 1", reactive(input$start))
   m2_handler <- m2_server("m2", "text 2", m1_handler$finished)
   
   current_status <- reactiveVal(0)
   
   observeEvent({
      m1_handler$trigger_update()
      m2_handler$trigger_update()
   }, {
      current_status(current_status() + 1)
      print(paste("Update", current_status()))
   },
   ignoreInit = TRUE
   )
   
   observeEvent(input$start, {
      progressSweetAlert(
         id = "progress",
         session = session,
         value = 0,
         total = 4,
      )
   }
   )
   
   observe({
      req(current_status() > 0)
      if (current_status() < 5) {
         updateProgressBar(session, "progress", value = current_status(), total = 4)
      } else {
         current_status(0)
         closeSweetAlert(session)
      }
   })
   
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```